# Ember link-to not working when not passed a model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, hyperlink

I have a template at the level just below the application route in my Ember application which contains a navbar with three tabs that should go to three sub routes. The link tos are set up like so:

```
{{#link-to "route.subroute.subroute-1"}}Route name{{/link-to}}
```

If you right click on the links, they work, but left clicking on them does not take you to the page. Nothing happens and no error. If you hard code a model id into the link like so it works:

```
{{#link-to "route.subroute.subroute-1" 1}}Route name{{/link-to}}
```

But passing a model name in place of the hard-coded id does not work, it merely adds a # to the end of the URL. How can I make this work?

Router.map(function() {

```
  this.route('/');
  this.route('route', function() {
    this.route('subroute', function() {
      this.route('subroute-1', { path: 'subroute-1/:route-1_id' });
      this.route('subroute-2', { path: 'subroute-2/:route-2_id' });
      this.route('subroute-3', { path: 'subroute-3/:route-3_id' });
    });
  });
});
```

I tried changing router to

```
this.route('/');
  this.route('route', function() {
    this.route('subroute', { path: 'subroute/:model_id' }, function() {
      this.route('subroute-1');
      this.route('subroute-2');
      this.route('subroute-3');
    });
  });
});
```

but then the findRecord('model', params.model_id) in the route/subroute/{id}/subroute-1 gets "ID passed to findRecord has to be number" error, and params.model_id is undefined.

Comment: You can't use the model's name, because in your router you probably wrote something like `this.route('route.subroute.subroute', { path: '/:some_id' });`. So ember expects a model object or an ID.

Comment: I tried {{#link-to "route.subroute.subroute" fake-model}}Route name{{/link-to}} and it doesn't work either. What should I change it to? fake-model.id also doesn't work, nor fakemodel fakeModel or fake_model.

Comment: Add your route and model file. There is too little context to tell...

Comment: Added a fairly redacted version of the router there. The template file is essentially three of the link-tos going to each of those subroute-# templates. I need to load the same model in each route though. Should I perhaps load it one level above?

Comment: Is it the same file you got problem ?. your linkto route should be like `route.subroute.subroute-1` instead of `route.subroute.subroute`

Comment: Yeah they are named correctly in the actual code. I'll edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are running into problems is because Ember's router expects an id (or model) to be passed as part of the `link-to` helper, based on what you provide in your Router map:

```
this.route('route', function() {
  this.route('subroute', function() {
    // the :route-1_id info here causes problems
    this.route('subroute-1', { path: 'subroute-1/:route-1_id' });
    this.route('subroute-2', { path: 'subroute-2/:route-2_id' });
    this.route('subroute-3', { path: 'subroute-3/:route-3_id' });
  });
});
```

If you don't have an id that you need for your sub route (that you intend to use to retrieve data from somewhere else), then you could do something like this:

```
this.route('route', function() {
  this.route('subroute', function() {
    this.route('subroute-1');
    this.route('subroute-2');
    this.route('subroute-3');
  });
});
```